# Python - Pandas - Replace a string from a column based on the value from other column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I've a dataframe with the following data:

```
d = {'col0': ['Table 1', 'Table 2'], 'col1': ['Tablename: Table 1', 'Tablename: Table 2'], 'col2': ['Table A', 'Table B']}
```

[image]

What I am trying is to replace on col2 the values that exists on col0 with the values from col2.

Basically my output it will be this:

[image]

I was trying to make a simple replace such as:

```
df['col3'] = df['col1'].replace(df.col0, df['col2'], regex = True)
print(df)
```

But it gives me `"TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments"`

Then I try this:

```
df['col3'] = df['col1'].replace(df.col0, str(df['col2']), regex = True)
print(df)
```

But it gives me a list on col3...

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a list or something list-like to the first and second parameters of `replace`. `.values` turns `df['col0']` and `df['col2']` into numpy arrays which will work.

```
df['col3'] = df['col1'].replace(df['col0'].values, df['col2'].values, regex = True)
```

Output:

```
      col0                col1     col2                col3
0  Table 1  Tablename: Table 1  Table A  Tablename: Table A
1  Table 2  Tablename: Table 2  Table B  Tablename: Table B
```

You can see the full documentation of `pd.DataFrame.replace` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).